# hide Reply Keyboard Markup in when send Inline Keyboard in lua

Tags: lua, telegram-bot

i need to remove replay markup keyboard from Previous chat when i send new inline keyboard my code same like to this :

```
 if msg.message.contact then

       local keyboard = {}
       keyboard.inline_keyboard = {
        { {text = 'yes',callback_data = 'yes_contact'},{text = 'no',callback_data = 'no_contact'}}
                            }
       sendmsg(msg.message.from.id,string.format("*your send number * \n` %s `\n confirm", msg.message.contact.phone_number),keyboard)
end
```

i try to use `keyboard.remove_keyboard = true` so i change code to

```
 local keyboard = {}
       keyboard.remove_keyboard = true,
       keyboard.inline_keyboard = {
        { {text = 'yes',callback_data = 'yes_contact'},{text = 'no',callback_data = 'no_contact'}}
                            }
```

but lua give me error .what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to type of `reply_markup` in [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), seems like it can only contain `InlineKeyboardMarkup` or `ReplyKeyboardRemove` :(

There has a workaround, you can send a messsage with `ReplyKeyboardRemove`, and use [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) to add your inline keyboard.

Comment: how i can get sended message_id from bot to use editMessageReplyMarkup?